# How to map a database view using Ruby ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, view

How to map a mysql database view using Ruby ActiveRecord in Rails?

Answer (score 4):

The book Enterprise Rails has a whole chapter on basing a model on a database view. [Here it is](http://books.google.com/books?id=thTju-4duY4C&lpg=PP1&ots=nFmsRSwKu0&dq=enterprise%20rails&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false) at Google Books.